# I have a 95GB invisible partition, how do I identify what it is for, so that I can eventually remove it

Tags: windows, partitioning, ssd

I have an old windows computer with a 500GB SSD (Crucial MX500), it shows 369GB free space.
The device manager shows a 95GB "Primary Partition" that has no drive letter (neither can I set one).

I would like to know what it is, potential suspect are:

- Linux boot
- Windows Hibernation
- Other unknown things

Any idea how I can inspect what it is so that I can safely remove it?

Thank you!

A screen of the device manager and the explorer (red square on the bizarre partition part):
[image]

Comment: Do you need to check it from that same Windows system or can you boot another OS?

Comment: It’s not used for hibernation, that’s a single file, on the system drive. You don’t appear to have any Linux partitions, and since it’s 100% unused, it’s safe to delete since it contains absolutely no data.

Comment: __Warning__: Disk Management just shows all unknown filesystems as 100% free. This does not mean there is actually no data on the partition! Do not rely on this information. // I suggest using some Live Linux to check the contents.

Comment: Question : In Disk Management, what is the full value of the "Status" field for this partition?

Comment: @harrymc it's in the graphical representation below: *Healthy (Primary Partition)*.

Comment: Run in an elevated CMD the command `diskpart` and enter `list volume`. Does it give any useful info about the partition in the "Fs" column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the information,

I finally tried to delete it, and it then said "This is another OS boot partition" (or similar), so I went ahead and removed it.

That information was not to be found elsewhere, so if you are in the same situation you can always try to delete the partition (you can decline of course) to see if it is another boot partition at least.

Cheers

Edit: spelling

Answer (score 0):

Most likely this partition is a recovery image which can be used with a recovery tool from the PC manufacturer to re-install the PC to a factory default state.
If you are OK with loosing that ability it is normally fine to delete.

If you absolutely want to be sure you need to boot with a Linux environment where you have more capable partition managers at your disposal so you can get more information about this partition.
A GParted Live USB stick is what I tend to use in such situations.